# Create Trigger on 2 tables from 2 differents bases

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, insert

Hello i'm working on a trigger. This trigger is able to compare data inserted in my table DOUBLON from base F with the data from CLIENT from base T.
If there is similar TEL, TELPOR, TELPRO, TELDOM, then it update F.DOUBLON.doublon = 'OUI' else it put in a 'NON'.
I created my trigger on on my base F on my table DOUBLON.

There is what I did:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER DoublonInserted
    ON  dbo.DOUBLON
    AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    DECLARE @doublon INTEGER
    SELECT @doublon = 0
    IF SELECT count(C.TEL)
    FROM T.dbo.CLIENT AS C , inserted AS I
    where I.TEL = C.TEL
    OR I.TEL = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TEL = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TEL = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TEL
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TEL
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TEL
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPOR) > 1
    BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.DOUBLON
    SET DOUBLON = 'OUI' --, @doublon = 0 
    FROM T.dbo.CLIENT AS C, inserted AS I
    where I.TEL = C.TEL
    OR I.TEL = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TEL = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TEL = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TEL
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TEL
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TEL
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPOR 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.DOUBLON
    SET DOUBLON = 'NON' --, @doublon = 0
    FROM T.dbo.CLIENT AS C, inserted AS I
    where I.TEL != C.TEL
    OR I.TEL != C.TELDOM
    OR I.TEL != C.TELPRO
    OR I.TEL != C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELDOM != C.TEL
    OR I.TELDOM != C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELDOM != C.TELPRO 
    OR I.TELDOM != C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELPRO != C.TEL
    OR I.TELPRO != C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELPRO != C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELPRO != C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELPOR != C.TEL
    OR I.TELPOR != C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELPOR != C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELPOR != C.TELPOR
    END
```

In the facts it's "work" Not in reality:

CASE WORKING.
Work if there is any duplicate in my insert, trigger set 'NON' in my column doublon for every lines inserted.
Work if there is only duplicate in my insert, trigger set 'OUI' in my column doublon for every lines inserted.

CASE NOT WORKING.
Not working if there is duplicate and no duplicate inserted.

I tried to reset my var @doublon but still the same.

I noticed that, my trigger put the last result of my test on all line for column doublon. If the latest insert is a duplicate data all line will have 'Yes' (**NOT vice-versa**).

I would like to have help to explain me why, or another way to do it ( **with Trigger**).

**I can't touch the database T (add column etc forbidden) !**

++ Bases are on the same server ++

Thanks for your time and you help !

EDIT :

Table CLIENT

[image: Table CLIENT]

Table DOUBLON

[image: Table DOUBLON]

ID_CLIENT -> int

What I want :
Set correct value on Doublon

Everything else varchar(50)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Can you get a native english speaker to help you re-write your question?   I tried to read it, and I just can't.

Comment: You have some serious logic issues here. First of all your update statements are going to update every row in DOUBLON. Secondly, if the first condition is true it will run only the first update statement, otherwise it will run the second one. You might have data in your insert that satisfies both conditions.

Comment: I will try your syntax @marc_s thank for the tips !

Comment: We don't want to write row by row anything. Instead it should be set based updates. I can't really offer much here because I don't know what your tables look like. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Ok i will check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright ! Here is "the answer" :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER DoublonInserted 
ON dbo.DOUBLON
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
    BEGIN

INSERT INTO DOUBLON
(
    ID_CLIENT
    , NOM
    , PRENOM
    , TEL
    , TELDOM
    , TELPRO
    , TELPOR
    , DOUBLON
)
select i.ID_CLIENT
    , i.NOM
    , i.PRENOM
    , i.TEL
    , i.TELDOM
    , i.TELPRO
    , i.TELPOR
    ,  CASE 
            when I.TEL = C.TEL
OR I.TEL = C.TELDOM
OR I.TEL = C.TELPRO
OR I.TEL = C.TELPOR
OR I.TELDOM = C.TEL
OR I.TELDOM = C.TELDOM 
OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPRO
OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPOR
OR I.TELPRO = C.TEL
OR I.TELPRO = C.TELDOM 
OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPRO
OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPOR
OR I.TELPOR = C.TEL
OR I.TELPOR = C.TELDOM 
OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPRO
OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPOR
            THEN 'OUI'
            ELSE 'NON'
        END
FROM inserted AS I
left join T.dbo.CLIENT AS C 
on I.TEL = C.TEL
OR I.TEL = C.TELDOMICIL
OR I.TEL = C.TELPRO
OR I.TEL = C.TELPOR
OR I.TELDOM = C.TEL
OR I.TELDOM = C.TELDOM
OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPRO
OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPOR
OR I.TELPRO = C.TEL
OR I.TELPRO = C.TELDOM
OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPRO
OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPOR
OR I.TELPOR = C.TEL
OR I.TELPOR = C.TELDOM
OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPRO
OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPOR
END
```

Thanks to @Sean Lange (you did it !), @Bohemian♦ and everyone else !

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are after now. Here is how you could create this as an instead of trigger. This should be pretty close.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DoublonInserted 
    ON dbo.DOUBLON
    INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT DOUBLON
    (
        ID_CLIENT
        , NOM
        , PRENOM
        , TEL
        , TELDOM
        , TELPRO
        , TELPOR
        , DOUBLON
    )
    select i.ID_CLIENT
        , i.NOM
        , i.PRENOM
        , i.TEL
        , i.TELDOM
        , i.TELPRO
        , i.TELPOR
        , case when 
                I.TEL = C.TEL
                OR I.TEL = C.TELDOM
                OR I.TEL = C.TELPRO
                OR I.TEL = C.TELPOR
                OR I.TELDOM = C.TEL
                OR I.TELDOM = C.TELDOM
                OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPRO
                OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPOR
                OR I.TELPRO = C.TEL
                OR I.TELPRO = C.TELDOM
                OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPRO
                OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPOR
                OR I.TELPOR = C.TEL
                OR I.TELPOR = C.TELDOM
                OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPRO
                OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPOR
            THEN 'OUI'
            ELSE 'NON'
            END
    FROM inserted AS I
    join T.dbo.CLIENT AS C on c.ID_CLIENT = i.ID_CLIENT;
END
```

Still pretty vague on details but I think you want something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DoublonInserted 
    ON dbo.DOUBLON
    INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT DOUBLON
    (
        ID_CLIENT
        , NOM
        , PRENOM
        , TEL
        , TELDOM
        , TELPRO
        , TELPOR
        , DOUBLON
    )
    select i.ID_CLIENT
        , i.NOM
        , i.PRENOM
        , i.TEL
        , i.TELDOM
        , i.TELPRO
        , i.TELPOR
        ,  CASE 
                when C.TEL IS NULL
                    OR C.TELPRO IS NULL
                    OR C.TELDOM IS NULL
                    OR C.TELPOR IS NULL
                THEN 'NON'
                ELSE 'OUI'
            END
    FROM inserted AS I
    left join T.dbo.CLIENT AS C on I.TEL = C.TEL
                                OR I.TEL = C.TELPRO
                                OR I.TEL = C.TELDOM
                                OR I.TEL = C.TELPOR
END
```

Comment: c.ID_CLIENT = i.ID_CLIENT is every time FALSE 
because I insert from a CSV file and ID_CLIENT from this file start with 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: OK. I am guessing here because I have very little detail to work with. How do you know that a new row being inserted is related to an existing row in CLIENT? Perhaps you just need to modify the join predicates?

Comment: We don't want duplicate on TEL (phone number) so we test on this (what is on your " care when "). 
If all the data are the same except TEL, TELPRO, TELDOM, TELPOR between them then row is not considered like a duplicate.

Comment: @PandaRasta see my latest edit. I am still somewhat guessing at your requirements but I think this is closer to what you want.

Comment: I don't have access on DB for now so i wil test it in the morning tomorroy. Thank for you help and time !

Comment: I tested it. It works if the new(s) row(s) are not duplicate else an error is raised
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ID_CLIENT'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DOUBLON_TEST'. The duplicate key value is (4)." I checked my INSERT and error raise only when I try to add a duplicate
        
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DOUBLON_TEST] (ID_CLIENT, NOM, PRENOM, TEL, TELPOR)
        VALUES ('1', 'TEST1', 'TEST1','0666942574', '0666942574') // Not Work

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DOUBLON_TEST] (ID_CLIENT, NOM, PRENOM, TEL, TELPOR)
        VALUES ('1', 'TEST1', 'TEST1','066694', '0574') // Work

Comment: I delete data table DOUBLON after every test *

Comment: In my table CLIENT there is row with data in TEL or TELPOR and TELPRO and TELDOM are NULL so the data Inserted can is a duplicate just if CLIENT.TEL = INSERTED.TEL (or CLIENT.TEL = INSERTED.TELDOM,...etc) but the case when will not consider it like a duplicate right?
If yes I think we have to ignor NULL data

Answer (score 0):

You need only one "find a double" query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DoublonInserted
ON  dbo.DOUBLON
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
IF EXISTS(
    select * from
    FROM T.dbo.CLIENT AS C, inserted AS I
    where I.TEL = C.TEL
    OR I.TEL = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TEL = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TEL = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TEL
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELDOM = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TEL
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELPRO = C.TELPOR
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TEL
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELDOM
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPRO
    OR I.TELPOR = C.TELPOR)
    UPDATE dbo.DOUBLON
    SET DOUBLON = 'OUI'
    WHERE ID_CLIENT = I.ID_CLIENT;
ELSE
    UPDATE dbo.DOUBLON
    SET DOUBLON = 'NON'
    WHERE ID_CLIENT = I.ID_CLIENT;
END
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a BEFORE trigger in sql server. And the syntax posted here is not valid for sql server.

Comment: @sean how about now? (I don't speak sql server)

Comment: Yes ... I tried to do it like on Oracle db but sql server don't accept BEFORE that's why i wrote AFTER. Should I use INSTEAD OF ?

Comment: You would need joins in both of your updates. The logic seems fairly close but this would need to become an instead of trigger. And since this is an insert trigger we probably don't have a row in DOUBLON yet. And we still have the issue of the possibility that both results are true because triggers in sql server fire once per operation. If there are two rows being inserted the inserted virtual table would have two rows.

Comment: There is another problem. ID_CLIENT is different with I.ID_CLIENT
(don't ask me why I'm not the one who built the architecture...)

Comment: @PandaRasta do you want to update all the *existing* rows that are doubles of the new row?

Comment: There is any data on my table DOUBLON.
I INSERT (10, 50, or more row) so the trigger update the new row.
After that I extract my table DOUBLE and delete data.
@Bohemian